# Yii2 - RBAC, Difference between Roles and Permissions

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

How can I assign permission to specific user:

Role A

```
Permission A1

Permission A2
```

how can i say : if(Yii::$app->user->can('A1')){}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A role it is a symbolic value that is used to indicate a behavior and a set of actions (permissions) associated with this behavior. For example, a typical role is what distinguishes an administrator or a user who can only see (an observer),.

A permission  is the elementary level of action that is allowed to make. (edit, create or delete an object, for example).

A role is associated with a user.

So it is the administrator user is associated with the administrator role, while other user, for example, are associated with the role of observers rather than creators or modifiers.

Comment: Thank you @scaisEdge for your answer.
Specially in yii2, can you tell me how can i use user (permissions) inside my code to check his access?
ex: if(Yii::$app->user->can('<permission_name>'),
is there an ability to use this or its applicable only for (ROLES)?

Comment: I usually group a set of permissions (even just one) and check them to a role. so I tend to control access basing on roles. But you can try directly controlling access to the single permit. The syntax is exactly the one that you specified (Yii :: $ app-> User-> can ('admin') where `admin` is a role (or you can also try like a permission)